# Rails: Populating modal with data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, modal-dialog

I know this is an old question, but I cant get it solved..
I want to show a list of comments in a modal, specific to each iteration.

Content has_many comments, Comment belongs_to content`

```
@contents.each do |content| 
content.title
button_to('read', category_modal_path(:comment_id => content.id), remote: true, :class=> 'modal-trigger2', 'data-target'=>'modal3')
end
```

controller

```
def category_modal
@comments = Comment.online.where(content_id: params[:comment_id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

the modal

```
<div id="modal3" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
...here I want show the list of comments
```

category_modal.js

```
$('#modal3').html(<%= j( render partial: 'shared/modal2', locals: {comments: @comments} )%> );
```

coffee

```
$('.modal-trigger2').leanModal()
```

Modal opens but no data.. help would be very nice..

Comment: Did you check in response of ajax ? If the response has some data.

Comment: I get nil..May be my aproach is wrong. First thought was getting the content.id as integer in the modal and then query inside the modal..but may be a little rough?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after an hour efforts I am able to solve your issue. Follow these steps.

1. First of all remove `$('.modal-trigger2').leanModal()` from coffee script. It does not need any more.
2. In `category_modal.js` paste the following code

   ```
   $('#modal3').html("<div href='#modal3' id='content_<%=params[:comment_id] %>'><%= j( render partial: 'shared/modal2', locals: {comments: @comments} )%></div>");
   $('#content_<%=params[:comment_id]%>').leanModal();
   $('#content_<%=params[:comment_id]%>').trigger('click');
   ```
3. You might need to add `method: :get` on your category listing If your route is not of `post` type so

   ```
   @contents.each do |content| 
     content.title
     button_to('read', category_modal_path(:comment_id =>content.id), remote: true, :class=> 'modal-trigger2',method: :get)
   end
   ```

okay now tell me what was the issue.
Basically it was the mess of `leanModal` If you have used bootstap modal it would not be the problem.

Basically Whenever we call `leanModal` on any element It stops it default behaviour `i-e Click` So from now on when some one click on it , It open the popup in which it shows the corresponding content which was mentioned in `href` of the clicked item.

So when I call `$('.SomeClass').leanModal()` It will add a click event for all of the item having class `SomeClass` and open modal when some one click on it and show the content.

So in your case when you called  `$('.modal-trigger2').leanModal()` It simply added a click event for all of your Contents buttons and open the popup whenever you clicked on any of it. It even didn't send an ajax call to server. 
As you know initially there was not any content in `modal3` container that's why it opened empty modal.

So now what I did was to remove this call and moved all of the popup logic in `category_modal.js`
So whenever you click on a Content it send an ajax request to server. In JS view I am doing the same thing you were doing but now I added a wrapper around your `comments` and set the `ID` unique depending on your requested `content_id` .
After that I call `leanModal` on this newly created wrapper div.
And trigger the `click` event on it so modal will show automatically.

P.S

You don't necessarily need this dynamic ID stuff following code will also work .

```
$('#modal3').html("<div href='#modal3' id='leanModalContainer'><%= j( render partial: 'shared/modal2', locals: {comments: @comments} )%></div>");
$('#leanModalContainer').leanModal();
$('#leanModalContainer').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..really nice..I will check that..Greetings Werner

Comment: up to now.. cant get it working..1. Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript.2. modal does not open..ich will try later. Thanks anyway for your effort..